# ionic infinite scroll is not working after scrolling one time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4 with angular
I am trying to use infinite scroll
my .html page is:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        ID
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:2;">
        Date
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        Amount
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        Type
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        Status
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of dataList">
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        {{item.id}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:2;">
        {{item.created}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        {{item.total}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        <b *ngIf="item.type==1">Delivery</b>
        <b *ngIf="item.type==2">Pickup</b>
        <b *ngIf="item.type==3">Reservation</b>
        <b *ngIf="item.type==4">R with Food</b>
        <b *ngIf="item.type==5">QR</b>
        <b *ngIf="item.type==6">Catering</b>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col style="flex:1;">
        {{item.status}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  
  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
<ion-infinite-scroll-content
  loadingSpinner="bubbles"
  loadingText="Loading more data...">
</ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

and .ts page is:

```
loadData( event ) {
console.log('loadData called');
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Done');
  
  //loading some data from server

  event.target.complete();
  if (this.dataList.length > 100) {
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }
}, 500);
```

}

in constructor i am loading some data also at the beginning

now when i run it scroll works one time. it loads some data in first scroll.
after that scroll even does not fire.

what can be the problem.
can anyone please help?

Comment: did you applied any styles to grid or content ? and also did check dataList.length ?

Comment: I found the reason, the reason is if first load doesn't load enough data that is enough to scroll then next event doesn't fire. For example if i load 25 rows in each load then it works but if i load less rows ex. 5 riws then it doesn’t work. But i did not find the solution. Some people online suggest that its a bug of ionic but i am not sure. Can you please help.

Comment: why its loading less data ? the purpose of the infinite scroll is for loading more data if it doesn't have much data (no scroll) event will never fire, can you try with styles to enable scroll on default , like overflow-y scroll ??

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution?